# Powershell script to adjust a specific value in configuration in an app

Tags: powershell

Is there a way that I can configure a script to change one value in a .cfg file located in %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\ folder?

I have doubt since the folder is user folder has different values I worry that it won't work. %userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If it's a script to only affect the logged in user, the enviromental variable `%AppData%` is all you need to get to the user's `AppData\Roaming` folder. In **PowerShell**, enviromental variables can be accessed using the format `$env:AppData`. That can be used in an [*expansion string*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/variable-expansion-in-strings-and-here-strings/) (double quotes) to build a child path, i.e. `"$envAppData\Micosft"`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.